# Java: pass-by-value references in methods

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I read a few articles and similar question in Stackoverflow; however, I did not quite get an answer to my question.
Here is the code:

```
public class CoinFlipping {

    Random random = new Random();

    Boolean head = null;

    public void flip(Boolean b){
        b = random.nextBoolean();
    //      head = b; 
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        CoinFlipping cf = new CoinFlipping();
        cf.flip(cf.head);
        System.out.println("Head: "+cf.head);
    }

    }
```

I refer to this arcticle: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)
I can understand why that piece of code behaves as it does. When we call `new dog()` we basically create a new Dog object. I get it. However, the example that I provided seems to be confusing a bit. I am not creating an object in this case (aren't I?). I am changing a value. Then why in this case when I print results, I get `null` and not `true` or `false`?

Comment: `b = random.nextBoolean();` creates a new reference, so modifies the value of `b`, not the value referenced by `b`.

Comment: @AntonH:  b does not "reference a value."  b _has_ a value which is a reference to an object (or a null reference).  The assignment statement gives b a new value (i.e., a reference to a new object).

Comment: @jameslarge I was trying to simplify, so that OP would see what was wrong. But too much, apparently.

Comment: there are answers on the linked question that directly address this. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40507/217324  closing this as a duplicate.

Comment: @AntonH Hello, so am I getting this right? When I pass any objects to methods, following happens: It looks up the value of the object through the reference, copies it and this copy is assigned to the local var (argument)? In this case I have another question. Is there any ways to pass a reference to method, so that I could take this reference, access the object and change it internal state? Is there a way to actually have a reference to an original object but not to copy inside of the method?

Comment: @George: not quite. it copies the reference (think reference = memory address) and passes *that* on. so the original reference can never change, what changes in the method is a separate pointer that was initialized using the reference originally, but now there's no connection.

Comment: @NathanHughes Yes, I create a second reference to the same object, right? But I do not change the reference. I change the object that this reference is referring to. Am I wrong? I am not doing anything with reference b (not assigning to another object), I am trying to change the state of the object it is referring to.

Comment: @George: i think you are confused (which you say up front of course). if you can reword this to make your question more specific i'm ok with reopening. but in its present form i don't think this question is going to get you any better answers. and if you wanted to change the state of the object you would call b.something, that still works. the method is changing the reference to point to a different object.

Comment: @NathanHughes actually, I think I get it. I am changing the local reference. Boolean is immutable so when I say ` b = random.nextBoolean();` I do not actually change original `head` value, right? I assign a new value (new object) to Boolean b. So, when I quit the method the original object is not changed and the one that was created has not reference (b is deleted), so it would be taken by a garbage collector. Am I right? If yes, in this case, I guess, there is not point to rename and reopen it.

Comment: @George: that sounds much better. your object's reference to head is unchanged by what goes on in the method, java is keeping that separate intentionally.

Comment: All right, seems to be clear. I guess it was also a question of what is mutable and what is not. This article helped:
http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2003/04/immutable.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `b` is passed by value, even though `b` is itself a reference.  Thus, when you call `flip`, the `flip` method treats `b` as a local variable that is a *copy* of what you pass into it.  Changing this copy doesn't change `cf.head`.

If `b` were a reference to a mutable object, you could change the object `b` refers to, and that change would be seen by the rest of the program after `flip` returns.  But a change to `b` itself is a change to a copy, and any such change will not be seen by the rest of the program.  (`Boolean` is not mutable.)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

> Then why in this case when I print results, I get **null** and not **true** or **false**?

I have created a **step-by-step walktrough** of your code to show you the pointers (references) of the specific variables and answer why it prints out `null` in the end:

**1. Step: New CoinfFlipping object is created with default field values**

> ```
> CoinFlipping cf = new CoinFlipping();
> ```

Inside the `CoinFlipping` class:

> ```
> Random random = new Random();
> Boolean head = null;
> ```

`cf` ---- points to ----> `CoinFlipping` object
`cf.random` ---- points to ----> `Random` object
`cf.head` ---- points to ----> `null`

**2. Step: Calling the `flip` method with `cf.head` as parameter on the `cf` object**

> ```
> cf.flip(cf.head);
> ```

When evoking this method, a variable `b` is created inside the scope of the `flip` method.
The pointer (reference) from `cf.head` is copied into the variable `b`.
So `cf.head` and `b` point then at the same thing.

> ```
> public void flip(Boolean b){
> ```

`cf` ---- points to ----> `CoinFlipping` object
`cf.random` ---- points to ----> `Random` object
`cf.head` ---- points to ----> `null`
`b` ---- points to ----> `null`

**3. Step: Inside the `flip` method `b` is being reassigned**

> ```
> b = random.nextBoolean();
> ```

`cf` ---- points to ----> `CoinFlipping` object
`cf.random` ---- points to ----> `Random` object
`cf.head` ---- points to ----> `null`
`b` ---- points to ----> a `boolean` value - either `true` or `false`

**4. Step: Back in the main method to print out `cf.head`**

> ```
> System.out.println("Head: "+cf.head);
> ```

`cf` ---- points to ----> `CoinFlipping` object
`cf.random` ---- points to ----> `Random` object
`cf.head` ---- points to ----> `null`
`b` ---- points to ----> a `boolean` value - either `true` or `false`

**As you can see, `cf.head` is still pointing to  `null`, therefore `null` is being printed.**

*Solution:* 
To change this, you could let the method return a boolean value instead and assign that to `cf.head` in order to make `cf.head` point to a new boolean value.